# MATLAB Finding & printing a position of a specific value in a matrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I'm trying to find the location of all Zeroes in a matrix B, and print them

```
B=randi([-1 4],5)

 0    -1     1     1     2
 1     0     0     4     0
 1     1     0    -1     2
 3    -1     4     3     0
 3     2     3     3    -1

 [x,y]=find(B==0)

x =
 1
 2
 2
 3
 2
 4

y =
 1
 2
 3
 3
 5
 5
```

So, the zeroes are located in (1,1) (2,2) (2,3) (3,3) (2,5) (4,5).
And I want them to be printed as 1x1, 2x2, 2x3, 3x3, 2x5, 4x5

It's easy to read the x,y pairs using 'find(A==)' code, but it will be difficult
if the size of the matrix grows. Say, like the size of matrix B is 99X99. How will I find the locations of all zeroes, and print them?

So I tried to write a code that does it, but I keep failing.

```
[x,y]=find(B==0);

for i=1:length(x)

    for j=1:length(y)

    end 

    fprintf('%g x %g\n',x(i),y(j))

end
```

And I run my script.

```
>> Untitled8

1 x 5

2 x 5

2 x 5

3 x 5

2 x 5

4 x 5
```

So my MATLAB code correctly found the x-location (row #) of zeroes, but printed only 5 for y-location (column #).

I think it is because nested for loop repeats and finishes the inner loop, and then move on to the outer loop.

Is there anyway that the i and j increases simultaneously at the same time, so that I can print the locations of zeroes in the matrix?

Thank you

Comment: Why not just `disp([x y])`? Do you really need that `x` in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[x,y]=find(B==0);

for i=1:length(x)

    fprintf('%g x %g\n',x(i),y(i))

end
```

Vectors x and y have the same length and the pairs you want to print have the same index number in these vectors.

Comment: @EricKim please accept the answer if this solved your problem.

Comment: I'm new to this website, and I'm not sure if I accepted your answer, but I clicked the check mark next to your answer. Is that how it works here?

Answer (score 0):

You need `[row,col]=find(~X)`, see MATLAB reference [here](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html#budq84b-1)